# Recipe calling for LME or DME

Tags: dme, lme

I'm a bit new to extract brewing and am a bit confused about the following recipe.

[Red Hawk Ale](http://byo.com/light-ale/item/1309-red-hawk-ale)

It says it requires:

> 6 lbs. amber malt extract

Does this refer to 6 lbs. of [amber spray-malt](https://www.thehomebrewcompany.ie/spraydried-malt-extract-amber-3kg-p-182.html), [amber liquid malt extract](https://www.thehomebrewcompany.ie/coopers-malt-extract-amber-15kg-p-816.html) or either?

Thanks!

Comment: There is ambiguity there. Someone maybe could do the maths and estimated the SG for you? I imagine the difference between 6lbs liquid and dry to be noticeable. Otherwise I'll agree with BrianV and say its liquid.

Comment: If I remember right BYO designates dried as dried and where not designated it is implied as liquid.

Comment: I agree that it is probably liquid. But @ brewchez, BYO *does* designate liquid/syrup and dry in most recipes: [example from 1997](https://byo.com/stories/item/131-american-ipa). I note that OP's recipe also does not state what kind of crystal malt to use, and OP may be better served to find a more precise recipe, considering that there are probably thousands of American IPA recipes available on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume they mean liquid malt extract as the specifically mention dry light malt extract below.